# In android I want fetch .svg imageUrl from server on imageView for my android project, but i am getting distorted image on imageview

Tags: android, svg

```
private void fetchSvgImage() {
    requestBuilder = Glide.with(this)
            .using(Glide.buildStreamModelLoader(Uri.class, this), InputStream.class)
            .from(Uri.class)
            .as(SVG.class)
            .transcode(new SvgDrawableTranscoder(), PictureDrawable.class)
            .sourceEncoder(new StreamEncoder())
            .cacheDecoder(new FileToStreamDecoder<SVG>(new SvgDecoder()))
            .decoder(new SvgDecoder())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.empty_photo)
            .error(R.drawable.empty_photo)
            .animate(android.R.anim.fade_in)
            .listener(new SvgSoftwareLayerSetter<Uri>());
  }

private void reload() {
    loadNet();
  }

  private void loadNet() {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(Utils.getStringValue(tripAdviser.getRatingImageUrl()));
    requestBuilder.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
            // SVG cannot be serialized so it's not worth to cache it
            .load(uri)
            .into(topTripAdviserImage);
  }
```

In android I want fetch .svg imageUrl from server on imageView for my android project, but i am getting distorted image on imageview.

I am using this link as reference. https://github.com/bumptech/glide/tree/v3.6.0/samples/svg/src/main/java/com/bumptech/svgsample/app.

Comment: Distorted how?  How is your `ImageView` defined?  What does your SVG image look like?

Comment: Distorted means it's not same what should I get image from server.

Comment: Please post the original image and the resultant image?